# How to pause a javascript method without wasting computation?

Tags: javascript

Essentially, how do you pause javascript execution without having to waste computation on something like a while loop?

For example, say I want to only perform a function next after 10 seconds and not interrupt other processes or waste computation? `setTimeout` won't work because I want the processes to actually pause / not continue any operations during that time.

```js
const next = () => console.log("next");

/** pause for 10 seconds */

next()
```

Also what if I want to only run a method conditionally, where every couple seconds or something I can either abort the operation or continue. Notably I don't mean to use `setInterval` because in that case it's not actually conditionally pausing the actual javascript execution.

```js
const next = () => console.log("next");

const start = new Date();
const startSeconds = now.getSeconds();
const checkEvery = 1; // seconds
const requiredDiff = 10; // seconds

const checker = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    let secondsNow = now.getSeconds();
    secondsNow < startSeconds ? secondsNow += 60 : null;
    
    const diff = secondsNow - startSeconds;
    if (diff < 10) {
        return false
    }
    return true;
}

/** something that runs checker every 1 seconds and pauses computation until checker() returns true and then runs next() */
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: A modal window or a debugging breakpoint would stop the execution of all the processes. But it seems like you can not continue automatically. `sleep()` can pause the current process.

Comment: Where does the ja code run? Browser, electron, nodejs, ... ? `I want the processes to actually pause / not continue any operations during that time.` what are those other operations that should not run on pause?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is by creating a block in the pipe. i.e.

`process -> pause -> next` so that you can know that the flow of the program won't continue until a certain criteria is met

You can do this by pausing things inline

```js
...
await pause();
...
```

where `pause` is something that does a timed-out promise or something along those lines. I don't know too much about this method, but it seems relatively complicated.

Another way to do this is by stopping the execution inline with a while loop

```js
...
// pause for 10 seconds
let result;
while (!result) { result = checker() };
...
```

but as you alluded to, this wastes a lot of operations and can interfere with other actions in the background from running properly. Another thing is you can't only check checker every 1 second.

I suggest you do the following instead:

```js
const max = 20; // max number of recursive calls (i.e. timeout after 20 seconds)

// checker is a function that returns true or false and is agnostic to this implementation
// timeout is the time (in milliseconds) to wait before running the checker again
// next is the next step in your pipeline that you want to prevent from e
const pause = async (checker, timeout, next, calls = 0) => {
    if (calls > max) return; // prevents stack overflow
    const result = await checker(); // just in case your checker is async

    // if the condition was met then continue on to the next stage in your pipeline
    // if the condition was not met then run this method again to re-check in timeout
    result ? next() : setTimeout(() => pause(checker, timeout, next, calls + 1), timeout)
}

// with the functions you provided...
pause(checker, 1000, next)
```

`pause` will only execute operations when the timeout is met, and it won't allow the program to continue to the next stage until the checker is met.